# Wrapping texts inside action button

Tags: html, r, shiny

The below HTML code renders properly on shiny

```
> HTML(paste0(strwrap('I saw a beautiful moon tonight',width=10), collapse="\n"))
I saw a
beautiful
moon
tonight
```

But when the same in wrapped inside the action button, it is not

```
actionButton("df", HTML(paste0(strwrap('I saw a beautiful moon tonight',width=10), collapse="\n")))
```

[image]

Expected output

Even inside the button , the sentence should be split into 4 lines

Answer (score 3):

Use `br` html tag instead of `\n` for breaklines:

```
actionButton("df", HTML(paste0(strwrap('I saw a beautiful moon tonight',width=10), collapse="</br>")))
```